# How to install mpdf v8 with composer (currently it only installs v6)

Tags: installation, mpdf

I am on ubuntu 12.04 and trying to install the latest release (v8) of mPDF using the following command:

composer require mpdf/mpdf

However, only v6 gets installed.
Is there any easy way to install version 7 or 8 of mPDF - or is it quite a long process?

---

UPDATE

After running composer require mpdf/mpdf:^8.0
it looks like the PHP version on the server is 5.3.0.
Although none of the domains on the server use this (I use plesk to force all domains to use 7.1).

Comment: Show your other dependencies (contents of your require block in composer.json), some of them apparently conflict with newer mpdf versions. Optionally try running `composer require mpdf/mpdf:^8.0` - composer will tell you what the conflict is. Update your question with the output.

Comment: Since it seems you solved your problem, consider either deleting the question or adding an answer yourself and accepting it, so that this shows as solved.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP version on the server was a lot older than used by plesk.
As composer was looking at the older version, we could download a more recent version of mpdf.